# Allocated matrix and input file

Tags: fortran

I have an input data file storing two columns (first column contains the names of the variables and the second column contains their values). I am trying to read this input file through my FORTRAN script and to print on the screen the variables I've just created.

Here are the input file, the script, as well as the terminal output displayed on the terminal at the execution:

**input file:**

```
a    7 2 4
b    150
vec1 1 2 3
vec2 4 5 6 
c    56
```

**script**

```
program main
implicit none
character(16) :: cinput
integer :: a0,a1,a2,b0,c0,i,j
integer,dimension(:,:),allocatable :: gfd
open(9, file='inputdata.dat')
read(9,*) cinput,a0,a1,a2
read(9,*) cinput,b0
allocate(gfd(3,2))
read(9,*) cinput,gfd(:,1)
read(9,*) cinput,gfd(:,2)
read(9,*) cinput,c0
close(9)
write(*,*) 'a0=', a0,'a1=', a1,'a2=', a2,'b0=', b0,'c0=', c0
do j=1,2
    do i=1,3
        write(*,*) gfd(i,j)
    enddo
enddo
end program main
```

**Output on the terminal**

```
a0 = 7, a1 = 2, a2 = 4, b0 = 150, c0 = 56
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Now, this is good, but would there be a way to assign the values to the variable "gfd" without having to specify the size of the array in "allocate"? I could then modify the input file with a longer/smaller array, without having to modify the script when I allocate the variable "gfd".

Thank you for your support if you can help me!
ms518

*EDIT*: thanks for your answer, this procedure is working and it is now possible to work with various array sizes in the input file without having to modify the fortran script. Below are the modifications in inputfile, script and the result obtained.

**input file:**

```
size 5 2
a    7 2 4
b    150
vec1 1 2 3 4 5
vec2 6 7 8 9 10
c    56
```

**script**

```
program main
implicit none
character(16) :: cinput
integer :: a0,a1,a2,b0,c0,i,j, rows, cols
integer,dimension(:,:),allocatable :: gfd
open(9, file='inputdata.dat')
read(9,*) cinput,rows,cols
read(9,*) cinput,a0,a1,a2
read(9,*) cinput,b0
allocate(gfd(rows,cols))
read(9,*) cinput,gfd(:,1)
read(9,*) cinput,gfd(:,2)
read(9,*) cinput,c0
close(9)
write(*,*) 'a0=', a0,'a1=', a1,'a2=', a2,'b0=', b0,'c0=', c0
do j=1,cols
    do i=1,rows
        write(*,*) gfd(i,j)
    enddo
enddo
end program main
```

**Output on the terminal**

```
a0 = 7, a1 = 2, a2 = 4, b0 = 150, c0 = 56
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: Your new question is fine. One well meant warning. I suggested editing the first question, instead of deleting it and asking a new question, because if you have too many deleted questions or answers the system could automatically ban you. But you shouldn't still be close to it, just be careful. Editing and re-openning is often better.

Comment: All right Vladimir, thank you for the heads up. I thought deleting the previous one and opening a new question would be clearer. I'll now know everything for the next time

Answer (score 0):

The best way to specify the size of the array would be to include its dimensions in the input file, read them, allocate the array, then read the array.

If you need assistance programming this, modify your question.  You could, if you want, post your revised code to answer your own question.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed. I'll edit my post and include my revised code at the end